# How to merge different keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two Model classes

```
class Book
  # attributes
  # title
  # status
  # author_id
  belongs_to :author
  enum status: %w[pending published progress]
 end

class Author
  # attributes
  has_many :books
end
```

I have an activerecord that return a list of books

The list

```
[<#Book><#Book><#Book>]
```

I use this function to group them

```
def group_by_gender_and_status
   books.group_by { |book| book.author.gender }
      .transform_values { |books| books.group_by(&:status).transform_values(&:count) }
end
```

and the outcome is

```
{  
    "female"=>{"progress"=>2, "pending"=>1, "published"=>2}, 
     "male"=>{"published"=>3, "pending"=>4, "progress"=>4}
}
```

How do I merge `progress` and `pending` and name the key `pending`? so it would look like this

```
{  
    "female"=>{"pending"=>3, "published"=>2 }, 
     "male"=>{"pending"=>8, "published"=>3,  }
}
```

I prefer to use the `group_by` method vs the `group` by SQL for a reason. Thanks

Comment: `books.group_by {|book| book.status == 'progress' ? 'pending' : book.status }...`

Comment: Thanks but its not working

Comment: I think @AbM is right, did you maybe not copy his answer to the right place in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_by_gender_and_status
   books.group_by { |book| book.author.gender }.
   transform_values do |books| 
       books.group_by { |book| book.status == 'progress' ?  'pending' : book.status }.
           transform_values(&:count) 
   end
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.